# When to use useEffect without dependencies vs. direct assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing a React hook that allows me to use `setInterval` in my components. In order to do so I need to keep the latest version of the callback in a ref so that it can be accessed from the scope of the interval later on.

This is my code so far:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function useInterval(
  callback: () => void,
  delay: number | null,
) {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback)

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    // Don't schedule if no delay is specified.
    if (delay === null) {
      return
    }

    const id = setInterval(() => callbackRef.current(), delay)

    return () => clearInterval(id)
  }, [delay])
}
```

My question is about the first instance of `useEffect` where the latest value is passed to the ref. According the the React documentation this code will execute after my component has rendered.

I can imagine this is useful when you are passing a ref to an element so you can be sure that it has a value after it has rendered. But if my code doesn't care about when the component renders, does it still make sense to keep this in a `useEffect`?

Would it make sense that I rewrite the code as follows:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function useInterval(
  callback: () => void,
  delay: number | null,
) {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback)

  // Remember the latest callback.
  callbackRef.current = callback

  useEffect(() => {
    // Don't schedule if no delay is specified.
    if (delay === null) {
      return
    }

    const id = setInterval(() => callbackRef.current(), delay)

    return () => clearInterval(id)
  }, [delay])
}
```

Comment: If you omit the second parameter in useEffect, it will execute that code on the first render and on every re-render, in which case, useEffect has no effect and you might as well just put it in the body of the function. If you have eslint enabled, it should actually complain to you when you do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### When to use `useEffect` without dependencies vs. direct assignment?

From docs:

> The [Effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) Hook lets you perform side effects in function components

- A `useEffect` without dependencies (or `undefined` as dependencies) will be run at first render and **every** subsequent re-render, *But* always as a side-effect i.e. **after** the component has rendered.
- A direct assignment (a sync operation) will be run at first render and **every** subsequent re-render, But always as in the render cycle. It may affect performance or **delay** the rendering.

So, when to use which one? It depends on your use case.

#### Which one to use in this (in question) use case?

I would say **neither**

```
useEffect(() => {
  callbackRef.current = callback
})
```

**nor**

```
callbackRef.current = callback
```

seems correct in this use case.

Because we don't want to do the assignment - `callbackRef.current = callback` at every re-render. But we want to do it when there is a change in `callback`. So, the below one seems **better**:

```
useEffect(() => {
  callbackRef.current = callback
}, [callback])
```

You may see [this blog](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) and [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57760842/2873538).

---

A demo which shows that an effect runs after as a side-effect (Log inside effect is always the last):

```js
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const callbackRef = React.useRef(callback)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(() => callbackRef.current(), delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [delay])
}

function Demo() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  function doThis() {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  useInterval(doThis, 1000)

  console.log('log - before effect')
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log inside effect')
  })
  console.log('log - after effect')

  return <h1>{count}</h1>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: "*we don't want to do the assignment `callbackRef.current = callback` at every re-render, but we want to do it when there is a change in callback.*" - well, if it doesn't change it's value, then `callbackRef.current = callback` would be a no-op. Nothing wrong with running the assignment over and over. Much more efficient than using an extra `useEffect` hook. And also potentially wrong, if `callbackRef.current` is used synchronously during the rendering, before the effect has run.